# How to work the window blinds

Tags: word-usage

Are the following expressions suitable while asking someone to cover  and uncover the window with the blinds?

> - spread the blinds over the window
> - pull away the blinds

Secondly, how to ask someone to move forward one step or move back one step?

Could someone update me as I have never come across any suitable usage for the above situations?

Answer (score 1):

Your phrases would be understandable, but typically we **raise** or **lower** blinds.

We can also **draw** the blinds, which can mean movement in either direction, as in [drawing the curtains.](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/draw_the_curtains)

Answer (score 0):

The sentences you have given are not necessarily incorrect, but they sound a little unnatural as they are literal directions. It would be better to use a singular verb just to combine everything you are trying to say. For example:

- Can you draw the blinds? (closing)
- Can you pull the blinds to (closing)
- Can you shut the blinds? (closing)
- Can you open the blinds? (opening)

I am not entirely sure of the context of your second question but to me, "can you move a step forwards/backwards?" sounds like a good option.

Comment: Your second bullet point is peculiar - is that a complete thought?  If so, I have never heard the expression before ("Pull the blinds to")